# Checking nearby cell for match

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of code that looks into a worksheet. This code should look through all the items in column A that have values, and then look one column to the right, to see if its neighbor in column B has a value. If the value in B exists, AND matches a certain criterion number, the value in column A gets copied into a collection (as an ID to display detailed information later).

```
 If criteriaNumberMatches > 0 Then
'Dim Element As Integer
'goal is to count the number of each unique Bearpass Number, and if its > 3 display user info

Dim totalCorrectHits As Integer

'THIS MAY NOT WORK
'look through the rows of the Extra Interface
For Each cell In Sheet4.Range("A2:A1000")
    If Len(cell.Value) <> 0 Then
        cellNextDoor = cell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1)
        'check to see if cell to the right has a value equal to the criteria matches
        If Len(cellNextDoor) <> 0 & cellNextDoor = criticaNumberMatches Then
            matchBPNcol.Add cell.Value
            totalCorrectHits = totalCorrectHits + 1
            MsgBox "Commander, we've found something!"
        'old code below
        'MsgBox cell.Value & "is the cell value, vs " & criteriaNumberMatches & " matches "
            'if the criteria hits = the number of criteria, add to collection
            'If cell.Value = criteriaNumberMatches Then
               'Look one cell left to find the BPN, and add it
               'thingToAdd = ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1)
               'THIS ALSO MAY NOT WORK
               'matchBPNcol.Add thingToAdd
               'totalCorrectHits = totalCorrectHits + 1
            End If
    End If
Next
Else: MsgBox "No Results Found"
End If
        MsgBox "There are " & criteriaNumberMatches & " criteria to match"
        MsgBox "The matchBPNcol contains " & matchBPNcol.Count & " positive matches in all criteria"
        MsgBox "There are " & totalCorrectHits & " totally unique BPN matches"
```

Consequently, at the end, I notice that my collection (`matchBPNcol`) is empty, and my `totalCorrectHits` is empty as well. I might be defining the cell to the right incorrectly.
The picture below is example of `criteriaNumberMatches = 2` but it isn't triggering each of the Bearpass Numbers to be added to `matchBPNcol`

[image: Example of criteriaNumberMatches = 2, should trigger hits]

Comment: VBA `And` operator is `And` :)... something wrong at this line `If Len(cellNextDoor) <> 0 & cellNextDoor = criticaNumberMatches Then`. `&` is used to join strings together

Comment: Bingo. Thank you for your help! I ended up finding this out later when rifling through the MS documentation on relational operators.
You're a brilliant person! Thank ye!

Comment: Commander, we've found your `&` ! XD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KS Sheon for the answer: my logic `If Len(cellNextDoor) <> 0 & cellNextDoor = criticaNumberMatches Then` contained `&` when it needed `And`. The first one is relational, the second one concatenates strings.